# Indent settings for atom-beautify with uncrustify for C/C++?

Tags: atom-editor, code-formatting, auto-indent

Where can the indent settings (tab width) be set for uncrustify run by the Atom package atom-beautify (on Windows)?
While the package settings offer to specify a path for an uncrustify config file (separately for C and C++), I can't figure out where the default settings come from.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The package directory is

- Windows: `C:\Users\<user>\.atom\packages\atom-beautify\src\beautifiers\uncrustify`

Uncrustify is run via `index.coffee`, resulting in arguments like:

```
C:\uncrustify\uncrustify.exe
-c
C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Local\Temp\.....cfg
-f
C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Local\Temp\input...
-o
C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Local\Temp\output...
-l
CPP
```

If no path is configured in settings, it generates a temporary config via `cfg.coffee`. It may just look like

```
indent_with_tabs = 0
output_tab_size = 2
input_tab_size = 2
```

This may not be enough for uncrustify to modify the source as intended. I am not sure from where these settings originate (Atom Editor Settings?). So I just modified `default.cfg` in the package directory (reduce tab width to 4, spaces for tabs -- not sure which parameter did it), added that to the settings, et voila...

Answer (score 0):

go to **Atom's top menu bar** -> **Packages** -> **Atom Beautify** -> **Settings** and **open the C section** as in the picture below:

[image]

there you must fill the **Config Path** with yours, mine, because I work on Ubuntu, was:

> /home/ungalcrys/.atom/packages/atom-beautify/src/beautifiers/uncrustify/default.cfg

on Windows it migt be:

> C:\Users\ungalcrys\.atom\packages\atom-beautify\src\beautifiers\uncrustify\default.cfg

`default.cfg` file already exists and you may have to comment one or two lines depending on the version of uncrustify.